# Please Help me understand this proof

Tags: logic

[image]

[image]

**DOUBT**

What i didnot understand is from where it is written our new goal means there exists a... I didnot understand how there exists word popped up here and why the new givens are written as they are, i mean using there exist and for all

Thanks

Comment: He has a premise : $F \cap G \ne \emptyset$ and an assumption : $x \in \cap F$. Consider the assumption : saying that the "intersection" of two families of sets $F$ and $G$ is not empty means that **there is** a set (call it $A$) that belongs to both $F$ and $G$, and thus to their intersection : $\exists A (A \in F \cap G)$.

Comment: The same for the *goal* : he wants to show that $x \in \cup G$; saying that  $x$ belongs to the "big-union" of a family of sets $G$ means that **there is** some set in the family (call it $A$) that contains $x$ : $\exists A \in G (x \in A)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Since the goal is a conditional statement, shouldn't the second given and goal should contain same symbol , either there exists or for all. So shouldn't it be there exists instead for all in second new given

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i mean since it is conditional statement(goal) so goal should have for all instead of there exists.

Comment: @TaylorTed: No, because the second given is a statement about the _intersection_ of the sets in $\mathcal F$, whereas the goal is a statement about the _union_ of the sets in $\mathcal G$. The intersection and union unfold to different quantifiers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no proof here. This is just a bunch of "preliminary work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of blabla in the excerpt shown. Before you are going into the finicky details of the logic atoms used in this proof you should understand it on a real world level.

We are given two families of sets ${\cal F}$ and ${\cal G}$, and are told that ${\cal F}\cap{\cal G}\ne\emptyset$. This means that there is at least one set $A$ belonging to both families.

We next consider the set $\cap{\cal F}$, which is shorthand for the intersection of all sets $X_\alpha\in{\cal F}$, and similarly $\cup{\cal G}$, which is shorthand for the union of all sets $Y_\beta\in {\cal G}$.

*Claim:*  $\quad{\cal F}\cap{\cal G}\ne\emptyset\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \cap{\cal F}\ \subset\ \cup{\cal G}$.

*Proof:* Any $x\in\cap{\cal F}$ belongs to every $X_\alpha\in{\cal F}$, in particular to the set $A\in{\cal F}\cap{\cal G}$ mentioned above. This set $A$ takes also part in the grand union $\cup{\cal G}$; therefore $x$ belongs to this union.$\quad\square$

Note that the proof took only two lines.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't even read the stuff before the claim but I think your proof is about as clear as it gets. One suggestion though: add the given condition to your claim. It might make it easier to follow the already easy to follow proof. +1

Answer (score 1):

We don't need to "choose" A. We know that at least one set A belongs to F and to G. The intersection of F is a subset of any such A, because A belongs to F, and any such A is a subset of union-G, because A belongs to G. QED.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough as a proof:

Let $\mathcal H=\mathcal F\cap\mathcal G$. As $\;\mathcal H\subset \mathcal F$, we have $\;\bigcap\mathcal F\subset\bigcap\mathcal H $.

Also $\;\bigcap \mathcal H\subset\bigcup \mathcal H $.

Finally, as  $\;\mathcal H\subset \mathcal G$, $\;\bigcup\mathcal H\subset \bigcup\mathcal G$. Then use transitivity of inclusion.

Comment: I think i haven't learned transitivity of inclusion yet

Comment: It's the transitivity of implications as well. Also, didn't you see inclusion is an order relation?

Comment: I donot know what you are talking about

Comment: Transitivity of implications is just the fact that $(p \to q)\wedge (q\to r)\to (p\to r)$.